# How to get twich emotes via API??

Tags: python, json, api

I need to download twich.tv emotes. I found Phyton script, but that not working. The man who wrote the script said Twich activate cloudfare or etc. That [page with API doc](https://twitchemotes.com/apidocs)

```
import urllib
import os
import json

if not os.path.exists('./emotes'):
    os.makedirs('./emotes')
print('Saving emotes to folder: ' + os.path.abspath('./emotes') + '...')
print('Grabbing emote list...')
emotes = json.load(urllib.urlopen('https://twitchemotes.com/api_cache/v2/global.json'))
for code, emote in emotes['emotes'].items():
    print('Downloading: ' + code + '...')
    urllib.urlretrieve('http:' + emotes['template']['large'].replace('{image_id}', str(emote['image_id'])),
                       './emotes/' + code + '.png')
print('Done! Kappa')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I don't think that API works anymore. Seems like you can use https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/emoticons/ though:

```
import urllib
import os
import json

if not os.path.exists('./emotes'):
    os.makedirs('./emotes')
print('Saving emotes to folder: ' + os.path.abspath('./emotes') + '...')
print('Grabbing emote list...')
emotes = json.load(urllib.urlopen('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/emoticons/'))
for emote in emotes['emoticons']:
    code = emote['regex']
    print('Downloading: ' + code + '...')
    urllib.urlretrieve(emote['images'][0]['url'], './emotes/' + code + '.png')
print('Done! Kappa')
```